# How to transfer my files from Ubuntu one to another cloud?

Tags: cloud-storage, mega

As we all know , Ubuntu one services are coming to an end.
I was wondering if there was a way to transfer files between ubuntu one and mega ?
If anybody has done something of the like please help.